# Set Outlook's 'show this address list first' option

Tags: powershell

I need to change default address list in outlook 2010 across thousands of computers.  To manually do it in outlook you go to address book>tools>options>and select an address book from the 'When opening the address book, show this address list first:' drop down box.

This is what I have so far:

```
$outlook = $(New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application)
$Session = $outlook.Session
$Session.Logon()
$ab = $Session.AddressLists | ? {$_.Name -eq 'Example Address Book')}
$abdialog = $Session.GetSelectNamesDialog()
$abdialog.InitialAddressList = $ab
```

The error I'm receiving is:

> Exception setting "InitialAddressList": "Cannot convert the "System._*ComObject" value of type
>   "System.*_ComObject#{00063049-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}" to type "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressList"."
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + $abdialog.InitialAddressList = $Session.AddressLists | ? {$_.name -eq 'BAE Syste ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

please help I'm going insane with this!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a typo but in :

```
$ab = $Session.AddressLists | ? {$_.Name -eq 'Example Address Book')}
```

You should remove the last closing bracket

```
$ab = $Session.AddressLists | ? {$_.Name -eq 'Example Address Book'}
```

After that your code works for me.

Comment: sorry yes that was a typo, if $ab is null then the command works properly, can you try replacing 'Example Address Book' with a address list in $Session.AddressLists in your environment to see if it works for you?